# In what way is the hypercube graph $Q_4$ non planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

According to Kuratowski's theorem, all non planar graphs must contain a subgraph that can be obtained from $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ (where $K_5$ represents complete graph containing $5$ vertices and $K_{3,3}$ is a $3$, $3$ complete bipartite graph). Does $Q_4$ contain a subgraph of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$?

If yes, then where is it located?

Comment: Reread Kuratowski, it isn't as simple as a subgraph must be $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the graph $Q_n$ you can easily find an subdivision of the graph $K_{n+1}$. Consider the vertices $v_0=0\dots0$ and $v_i=\overline{0\dots010\dots0}$ for $i\in[1,n]$ with the edges $v_0v_i$ and the subdivision $v_iv_j$ through the vertex $\overline{0\dots0\underbrace{1}_i0\dots0\underbrace{1}_j0\dots0}$.

Comment: Wikipedia has an illustration: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tesseract_graph_nonplanar_visual_proof.svg